# sscanf to uint8_t behaves different depending on variable order in structure body

Tags: c, gcc, scanf, uint8t

I've encountered strange behaviour when using sscanf. Depending on order of a and b in structure one of them is getting 0.

```
typedef struct MyStructure{
    uint8_t  a;
    uint8_t  b;
}MyStructure;
```

and here is code which gets me confused:

```
if (2 == sscanf(rawCommand,"%*s %*s %"SCNu8" %"SCNu8"", &a, &b)){
    ... some code
}
```

When I change order of variables in structure body to:

```
typedef struct MyStructure{
    uint8_t  b;
    uint8_t  a;
}MyStructure;
```

sscanf returns 2 but a is 0;

I've tested it on 32bit GCC on linux and above code works in both ways. But when compiling with 64bit GCC on windows 7 it behaves like I mentioned. On boths systems I'm using GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: You should show some typical input, i.e. the exact contents of the `rawCommand` string. Also your code is clearly wrong, since you're not doing structure access for `a` and `b`. Show *the exact code*, not some "artist's impression".

Comment: I think this: `"%*s %*s %"SCNu8" %"SCNu8""` means: Skip two strings, then scan 2 `SCNu8` type variables. `SCNu8` seems to be `#define` of some format specifier . Post more code for clarification.

Comment: @etheranger No, that's not what's happening, the asterisks suppress the assignment of the `%s` conversions.

Comment: In the `sscanf()` call, how could `&a` and `&b` be referring to the structure members? Shouldn't it be something like `&(mystruct.a)` and `&(mystruct.b)`?

Comment: @unwind My bad, I haven't used `scanf` and co for a while, apparently with good reason.

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild: `SCNu8` comes from POSIX's <inttypes.h>.